# Comics is or are

Tags: plural-forms

If I have a plural noun like "comics"  or "cartoons" should it be:

"Comics are an art form"  or "Comics is an art form", "Comics are art" or "Comics is art?"
If I am not mistaken, "Comics are an art form" and "Comics are art" are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. Someone who works on only one comic might say "I work in comic**s**", so in that context the plural 'comics' is used as a noun for the entire industry.

However, your example refers to the comics, not to the comic industry, or even the 'world' of comics. You wouldn't say "paintings is beautiful", nor would you say "comics is art".

As written, I'm confident that your example should be: "*comics **are** an art form*" because 'comics' *is* being used as a plural. Although "art form" is singular, the sentence does not pigeonhole all comics into one single art form. Comics themselves do not only feature one form of art - there is the classic comic strip style, Manga, the various ages of 'superhero' comics, and more recently digital art/colouring. Comics *are* an art form because they all feature a *kind* of art.

Examples of where "comics" is singular:

- The artwork in comics *is* true art.

"Artwork" is a true collective noun, so despite the fact the verb "is" appears right after the word "comics", it refers to the artwork. You could also use the term "comic art" in place of "the artwork in comics".

- Comics is a difficult business to break into.

As previously mentioned, "comics" can be used as a noun for the entire 'world' of comics or for the industry. If that is clear in your sentence, you can use it as a singular, collective noun.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. "Comics are art" is also correct, isn't it?  I mean can I omit "an art form"? I was thinking about collective nouns I have learnt and remembered some of them which take either a singular or a plural verb. For example, "family", "crew", "crowd", "company" so I decided to ask about "comics" and "cartoons". They must be exceptions.

Comment: @AntoniaA Yes! Comics *are* art! That is even better, as 'art' is uncountable. You can have a piece of art, but all art is art.